# What is missing from this code to help me export how many times a person wrote a review for specific items

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the total review count per profile when specific ASINs (products) are called.

For example, if I have 6 ASINs, I want to know if the person has written a product review for any of these ASINs. I am able to do this now.

But I am unable to do the following. If the person has written a review for more than 1 of the 6 asins, I want to know the total count.

Here's the code I am using:

```
select * from `reviewinfo` where `reviewAuthorURL` IN
(
SELECT `reviewAuthorURL` FROM `reviewinfo` WHERE `asin` in ('xxx','xxx','xxx', 'xxx','xxx','xxx', 'xxx','xxx','xxx', 'xxx','xxx', 'xxx') group by `reviewAuthorURL` HAVING COUNT(`reviewAuthorURL`)>1
    ) and `asin` IN
    (
    'xxx','xxx','xxx', 'xxx','xxx','xxx', 'xxx','xxx','xxx', 'xxx','xxx', 'xxx'
    )
```

Comment: Please tag properly.  This looks like `mysql`.  Please remove `sql-server` tag.

Comment: What is the first `SELECT` for?  What is the last `IN` for?  I think without those, you should get it.

Comment: Please don't deface questions/answers. You can censor stuff like the ASINs, but there's no reason (and it's actively harmful to the site) to wipe it all away. You can flag the question for a moderator to delete entirely if you want it off the site.

Comment: Thanks for that fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try just this code

```
SELECT `reviewAuthorURL`, COUNT(reviewAuthorURL) AS 'TheCount' 
FROM `reviewinfo` 
WHERE `asin` in ('xxx','xxx','xxx', 'xxx','xxx','xxx', 'xxx','xxx','xxx', 'xxx','xxx', 'xxx') 
GROUP BY `reviewAuthorURL` 
HAVING COUNT(`reviewAuthorURL`)>1
```

Try this edited query:

```
SELECT `asin`, COUNT(asin)
FROM `reviewinfo`
WHERE `reviewAuthorURL` IN
(
    SELECT `reviewAuthorURL`
    FROM `reviewinfo` 
    WHERE `asin` in ('xxx','xxx','xxx', 'xxx','xxx','xxx', 'xxx','xxx','xxx', 'xxx','xxx', 'xxx') 
    GROUP BY `reviewAuthorURL` 
    HAVING COUNT(`reviewAuthorURL`)>1
) 
GROUP BY `asin`
```